# Can't modify Turbo Ratio Limits

Tags: arch-linux, cpu

After installing `msrtools`, booting kernel with `msr.allow_writes=on`, loading the module using `modprobe msr` and setting `MSR_PLATFORM_INFO (0x0ce)` bit 28 to `1` I cannot modify `MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT (0x1ad)`.

I'm running Arch (rolling) with GNOME 41.2, kernel version `5.15.12-arch1-1`. CPU is an `i7-10750H`.

Am I missing something in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was in fact missing something in the BIOS, the option `Overclocking Lock` was `Enabled`... by disabling it I fixed the problem.